# What techniques are available to test if a character string is all spaces?

Tags: c, cstring

```
char *p = "   woohoo";

int condition = /* some calculation applied to p            */ 
                /* to look for all 0x20/blanks/spaces only  */ 

if (condition)
{
}
else
{
    printf("not ");
}

printf("all spaces\n");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One-liner:

```
int condition = strspn(p, " ") == strlen(p);
```

Slightly more optimized:

```
int condition = p[strspn(p, " ")] == '\0';
```

Comment: +1 The second is *significantly* optimised rather than *slightly* though, for the reasons discussed here: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: ya, it logically makes one pass over the string instead of 2.
How about an empty string?

Comment: Ya. this works for my situation.  An empty string yields true, which tells me there is no useful information in the cstring.

Comment: @Clifford, For practical purposes, it's only slightly faster.  Except for very large strings, I doubt there will be a difference, even with a million calls.  Feel free to benchmark to prove me wrong.

Comment: Also, the optimized version is less clear to the reader (at least, it's less clear to me on first sight).

Comment: It's a plus one sort of answer, in that there are people who have not run into strspn before.  That's part of what the question is for; New Ideas.   I had settled on the first example.  Then decided to ask the question.   I have switched to the second example in my actual code.

Comment: @strager: For large strings..., or a large number of small strings in an iteration.  I guess you did not read the article in the link!?  If it takes twice as long, it is true that you will not notice the difference between say 2 and 4 microseconds, but that is not the point at all.

Comment: @strager: w.r.t to clarity; that's what comments are for. An explicit intermediate variable will make it easier to follow too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fast way to do this, the best thing that comes to my mind is to write your own function (I assume you only search for ' ' characters) .

```
int yourOwnFunction(char *str, char c) {
    while(*str != '\0' && *str != c) {
        str++;
    }
    return *str == '\0';
}
```

So you just have to test

```
if(yourOwnFunction(p,' ')) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Correct me if I misunderstood something :)

Btw I didn't test it, but this should be in the worst case as fast as the other proposed method. If you just want a one-liner strager's (elegant) solution is the way to go!

Comment: It's nice in that it will short circuit out, when a non blank is encountered.